# libconfig not static linkage. how to compile into program

Tags: c++, unix, gcc, config, libconfig

I download the archive with libconfig, but I do not wont to install it into the system. I want to compile it as static library and link it from program girectory or directly link it into my program **on the program compile time**?

Any ideas how to do this with Makefile? (FreeBSD(UNIX), GCC)
or suggest other unix config libraries that support compilation into the program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On linux system untar then configure and make:

```
> ls
libconfig-1.4.8.tar.gz
> tar -zxvf libconfig-1.4.8.tar.gz
> cd libconfig-1.4.8
> ./configure prefix=/somewhere/in/your/homedir/doesnotmatter
> make
> ls -al lib/.libs
libconfig.a
libconfig++.a
...
other versions of lib
```

Then link your application against the static `.a` library.

```
gcc -I/dir/with/libconfigheader -o yourapp main.cpp libconfig.a
```

If you don't do `make install` it will not get **installed**, the libraries will be in the output directory, you can copy them where you need them.

I hope this helps.

**NOTE** I haven't tried to use the library, I just downloaded and compiled it ...

Comment: How can I link libconfig.a, libconfig++.a for makefiles?